Real division algebras with involution
Let $W$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{R}$-representation of finite group $G$. Schur's lemma implies that $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W)$ is a division ring. Since its centre is $\mathbb{R}$, $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W)$ is a central simple $\mathbb{R}$-division algebra.
Frobenius' theorem says that we have only three associative finite-dimensional real division algebras up to isomorphism: $ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C},$ and the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$.
Hurwitz's theorem says we have only four finite-dimensional real normed division algebras up to isomorphism: $ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H},$ and the octonions algebra $\mathbb{O}$, where $\mathbb{O}$ is not associative.
In my problem, $W$ is an orthogonal irreducible representation. Consequently, $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W)$ is endowed with involution that acts as operator adjoint. My aim is to write $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W)$  is isometrically isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C},$ or $\mathbb{H}$. Equivalently, I want to say there is *-algebra isomorphism $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W) \cong \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is either $ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C},$ or $\mathbb{H}$.
To do this, I have two options. My question is which option is better?

Option 1: Using Frobenius' theorem and then show that adjoint in $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W)$ corresponds to trivial involution in $\mathbb{R}$, complex conjugate in $\mathbb{C}$, or the standard involution in $\mathbb{H}$.

Option 2: Using Hurwitz's theorem and say there are only three associative finite-dimensional normed real division algebras, and so there is a *-algebra isomorphism between $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(W)$ and  $ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C},$ and $\mathbb{H}$.
Are both ways fine?
